# Get the Id of Office365 for the file API from SharePoint REST API

Tags: ios, sharepoint-2013, office365, adal, office365-apps

I'm working on an iOS app using the Office365 iOS SDK.

I'm also using the SharePoint REST API to search for files in the Office 365 SharePoint/OneDrive files. The search call looks like this:

```
.../search/query?querytext='myQuery'&SelectProperties='UniqueId,Title,Path,Size,Author'
```

The search works fine and gives me results. Now I want to download files from the search results. For this I am using the Office iOS SDK. To download a file, I need the ID of the file, as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/files-rest-operations#FileoperationsDownloadafileREST

In the iOS SDK, there's this corresponding method:

```
spClient.getfiles().getById(fileID)
```

The problem is, how do I get this fileID from the search REST API? I tried UniqueID but that doesn't work. Is there any way to get this ID?

Comment: I would expect the objects returned in the search results to have an 'id' attribute. Is that not the case?

Comment: No, unfortunately not, I can access more or less all managed properties of the SP search, e.g. ListItemId, UniqueID, etc. but none seems to corrrespond to the Id needed for the Office365 File API.

Answer (score 0):

`UniqueId` isn't a property of a File/Folder object. Selecting `Id` will return what you want. For reference, here are the properties of a [File/Folder object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/files-rest-operations#Itemresource).

**EDIT**: Here's the request I made to test this. `GET /_api/v1.0/me/files?$select=id,name,size HTTP/1.1`. Without pasting the entire response, I'll say I got what's expected, an array of File/Folder items with the ID, name, and size properties. Please let me know if you need more help!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem though, is that I use the SharePoint search API, not the files REST API and THEN I want to download the files I found from SharePoint search API with the files API.
The reason for that is, that search is currently not really implemented in the Office365/Files API, i.e. I saw that there is a $search method on the geFiles() but I couldn't find any documentation on that.